# Haskell "let" syntax in a way that it spans multiple rows

Tags: haskell, rows, let

Is it possible to write Haskell's "let" statement in  a way that it spans multiple rows ?

```
let a = " something in this row.


          something else in this row "
```

Or else , is there any other way to create a string which spans multiple rows ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To break up a string literal across multiple lines, use a string break like this:

```
let a = " something in this row.\
          \something else in this row\
          \ and more in this row\
          \ and yet more in this row "
```

You put a backslash at the end of each line you want to continue, and then another one at the start of the next line where the text will continue from.

Comment: What is it spans more than 3 rows ? I tried addding "\" in each and every line, but it generates an error

Comment: Just keep following the same pattern. I updated my example to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use multiple row expression if you use right indention.

For example,

```
multiLine = let a = if 1 == 2
                       then True else False
                 in a
```